# React router error: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

This code supposedly works on my previous projects. I wonder why typescript returns this kind of error:

```
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
(alias) createBrowserRouter(routes: RouteObject[], opts?: DOMRouterOpts | undefined): Router
import createBrowserRouter
```

`react-router-dom` version 6.14.1

```
import MainLayout from '../layouts/MainLayout';
import TodoListPage from '../components/pages/TodoListPage/TodoPage';
 
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';

const MainRoutes = {
  path: '/',
  element: <MainLayout />,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: (
        <ProtectedRoute>
          <TodoListPage />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      ),
    }, 
  ],
};

export default MainRoutes;
```

Error on this part:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([MainRoutes, AuthRoutes]);
```

The typescript error should be fix.

Answer (score 0):

As per your error, it says that it expects routes of the RouteObject[] type. You have to maintain it as you are using typescript.

the issue is,

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([MainRoutes, AuthRoutes]);
// this means that createBrowserRouter([RouteObject[], RouteObject[]]);
// and it expects createBrowserRouter([RouteObject[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I have fix it by adding src `ignorePatterns` in `.eslintrc`

```
ignorePatterns: [".eslintrc.cjs", "vite.config.ts", "src"],
```

Answer (score 0):

The `createBrowserRouter` function expects a "routes" argument that is an array of `RouteObject` object types. I can't exactly reproduce the error you face since my setup appears to *correctly* infer the object shape of `MainRoutes` and `AuthRoutes` to be a type match, but to resolve your issue you simply need to provide a type for your `MainRoutes` and `AuthRoutes` objects. You can import the `RouteObject` type from `react-router-dom`.

Example:

```
import type { RouteObject } from "react-router-dom";

const MainRoutes: RouteObject = {
  path: "/",
  element: <MainLayout />,
  children: [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: (
        <ProtectedRoute>
          <TodoListPage />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      )
    }
  ]
};

const AuthRoutes: RouteObject = {
  ...
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([MainRoutes, AuthRoutes]);
```